# Function to Return a Buttons OnClick Listener Value

Tags: android, onclick, return, return-value, onclicklistener

I was wondering If anyone knew of a way getting the On Click Listener a button is set to. Sort of like...

```
btn1.getOnClickListner
```

I want to make an IF Statement like this...

```
if (button.Onclick == onClick1) {
 do this...
} else {
 do this...
}
```

Any Help would be much Appreciated

Comment: Why not have just one `OnClickListener`, and have it branch inside of `onClick()` based on some state (e.g., a `boolean`)?

Comment: Because the button does not have the same onClick all time. It alternates between two onClicks. I'm trying to save what OnClick the button is set to in the saveInstanceState so I can restore it if the application changes to landscape mode. Also it would be a mountain of work as there are 7 Buttons with 14 OnClicks

Comment: "Because the button does not have the same onClick all time" -- and that is what I am suggesting that you change. Have the same `OnClickListener` all the time. Have that `OnClickListener` know how to do whatever it is that is needed, using appropriate state information. "Also it would be a mountain of work as there are 7 Buttons with 14 OnClicks" -- if you think that is a "mountain of work", you may run into many bigger mountains over time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the easiest way to do this was to take CommonsWares advice and create one onClick, using booleans to give it separate methods to execute. Below is an example in case anyone else gets stuck trying to accomplish this task. Thank you to everyone that helped and shared their thoughts.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    boolean separateOnClickActive;
    Button btn1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);

        separateOnClickActive = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                if (!separateOnClickActive) {
                    // Do Something Here
                    separateOnClickActive = true;
                } else {
                    //Do Something Here
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```